# Dropdown closes on clicking scrollbar of dropdown in a modal but works fine when used outside of a modal in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, autocomplete

I created an autocomplete component and when I use it in modal, the dropdown closes on clicking scrollbar(onBlur event of input gets fired) but when I use the same component outside of modal, scrolling with scrollbar works fine.

I am not able to find the cause of the issue. So please help!!

This is the [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-react-component-yqemc) link
(To reproduce the issue first use scrolling with scrollbar on main page, then open add item modal and use second input field in it which is same autocomplete component).

Comment: I've come across the same issue, except with bootstrap and angular.  I've discovered that if you remove the tabindex="-1" from the modal (ReactModal__Content) in dev tools it fixes the issue.  Not an ideal solution because we need that tabindex